# Why are the fees for converting Ripple to Bitcoin so high?

Tags: ripple, exchange-fees, ripple-transaction-fees

So I've very recently gotten into cryptocurrencies and after making a bit of money on bitcoin, I decided to try an altcoin. I used Changelly to convert my bitcoins into XRP and the fees were very low. Then, a few hours later I tried to convert 180 XRP (41 USD) to bitcoin using the same method. The "estimated amount" I would get (as indicated on Changelly) was quite close to this 41 USD amount, so I went ahead and exchanged. When the transaction was approved however, I only received 29 USD!!!! Is there something I did wrong? Is this normal? Why are the fees so high? Please do keep in mind that I've only started investing a few weeks ago. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely explained by the high fees on bitcoin. These services still have to move the bitcoin from one wallet to another and you have to pay a fortune at this time, about $6- $19.  You didn't do anything wrong this is something that will be fixed on the #bitcoin chain once #segwit and Lightning Network are highly adopted.